# What methods exist to give an iPhone an external hostname, on wifi or cellular data?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, vpn, dns

I want to give my iPhone (iOS7) a hostname, which will automatically resolve from anywhere as long as the phone is online. My iPhone can be jailbroken as part of the solution; that's not preventative. I'd prefer that the hostname be dynamically updated, but if not, I can script the polling/constant update. The goal is to not have to manually figure out/enter IP or routing information in order to remotely connect to my phone, regardless of whether the phone is connected via wifi or cellular data.

**What I've looked into:**

1. I've seen a few links as to how to [automatically have it update
   DynDNS or similar](http://gavcode.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/automatic-easydns-on-iphone/) with its **local** IP address, but that's not
   terribly useful, since I'd like to be able to access it remotely
   (not on the same LAN). There are sites which I could scrape that
   give me my external IP, but a lot of people seem to be of the
   opinion that [cellular providers do NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039848/could-i-connect-to-my-iphone-using-3g-ip) or similar IP
   consolodation, so that would invalidate the resolution of the
   hostname when the phone wasn't on wifi.
2. I could also run an always-on VPN from the phone, and have it either
   connect or proxy through a computer I control, one with an external
   IP, and have that computer NAT requests for the hostname to the
   iPhone. I know how to set up a VPN, but I don't know enough about
   how VPNs work over cellular data with an iPhone to set that up; if
   anyone knows more about this solution, please mention it in an
   answer.
3. I could also run a constant SSH reverse proxy or something like that
   (which sets up an always-open socket, push notification style, by
   initiating on the phone and keeping it open with the remote peer),
   and resolve the hostname on the peer and then somehow relay requests
   to the phone. Like the VPN idea, I know about this in theory, but
   don't really know where to start looking for info on how to
   configure it.

**Question:**

How do I give my (optionally jailbroken) iPhone an externally resolvable, preferably dynamically updated hostname on both wifi **and** cellular data?

Comment: would the other way around work also ? e.g. calling a host from the iPhone side ? I wrote a dyndns script some while ago to do the same thing. So you could tell your iphone to call a side (curl) every x minutes and the side (server) can tell you the exact information about your iphone. Might work, might not. I never tried it with an iPhone :D

Comment: Sure, but that assumes that the external IP is not NATed. For example, there could be a thousand iPhones behind one Verizon external IP, so sending requests to that IP would accomplish nothing at all. If I go that route, I need to know that the service provider is actually giving devices unique IPs. That seems doubtful, given the already-severe shortage of IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Actually, SSH'ing into my cellular IP iPhone works fine. I'm not sure where you can get that value without jailbreaking. Edit: Actually, of course you can log the IP  on a web server or similar.

Comment: Interesting. I'll test that with my provider. If it works, I'll let you know, and you can post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Regardless, if I were going to set this up, I would set my router to set a static IP to my iPhone based on the MAC address. I can use my external IP to get to the router (which can have a domain set up + DynDNS or similar because it's not a static IP). You may want to have a main system with services running that can route based on IP. This is very easy for web servers (just use nginx and `proxy_pass`, etc). For SSH and others, I'm not sure of an easy solution. You can also just set the iPhone SSH to another port and forward that port directly if you don't mind typing `-p PORT` every time.

Comment: Found this https://superuser.com/questions/366309/configure-router-to-redirect-different-hostnames-to-different-machines I have never found such an option in DD-WRT. I'm sure it's doable though

Comment: I actually have some spare external IPs, so I won't have to do any NATing based on hostname.